# How to return a set of rows of a cte defined within the function?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a function that's supposed to return all the children of a specific parent in a table of manager-employee relation.

I have the CTE that defines the recursivity of the problem working, but to allow any parent to be chosen I nested the CTE within a function. It creates the function but when I call it I get the error: query has no destination for result data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  display_full_cat(
    PROCURA VARCHAR
)
    RETURNS SETOF (categoria varchar, super_categoria varchar) AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        WITH RECURSIVE HIERARQUIA AS (
        SELECT C.CATEGORIA, C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
        FROM CONSTITUIDA C
        WHERE C.SUPER_CATEGORIA = PROCURA
        UNION
        SELECT C.CATEGORIA, C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
        FROM CONSTITUIDA C
        INNER JOIN HIERARQUIA H ON H.CATEGORIA = C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
    ) SELECT * FROM HIERARQUIA;

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM HIERARQUIA;
    RETURN;

    END
    $BODY$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

NOTE: CONSTITUIDA is the relation that contains the parent-child relation, which, respectively is super_categoria and categoria.

For the data

```
super_categoria | categoria
Organism        | Plant
Organism        | Animal
Animal          | Lion
Animal          | Cat
Plant           | Apple
Rock            | Obsidian
```

The result should be

```
super_categoria | categoria
Organism        | Plant
Organism        | Animal
Animal          | Lion
Animal          | Cat
Plant           | Apple
```

But I instead get the Error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function display_full_cat(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `RETURN QUERY` in the wrong location. It needs to be at the top of the CTE. You're already using `SELECT * FROM HIERARQUIA;` at the end of the CTE so the final query you're trying to return is duplicate. You're getting the error because of the `SELECT` at the end of the CTE not being stored or returned anywhere.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  display_full_cat(PROCURA VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF (categoria varchar, super_categoria varchar) 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY -- This will return the result from the last query in the CTE.
    WITH RECURSIVE HIERARQUIA 
    AS (
        SELECT C.CATEGORIA, C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
        FROM CONSTITUIDA C
        WHERE C.SUPER_CATEGORIA = PROCURA
        UNION
        SELECT C.CATEGORIA, C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
        FROM CONSTITUIDA C
        JOIN HIERARQUIA H ON H.CATEGORIA = C.SUPER_CATEGORIA
    ) SELECT * FROM HIERARQUIA; -- Prior to moving RETURN QUERY, this was causing the error
END;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```